# How do I install specific old versions of snaps, and is there a way I can find their dependency versions ahead of time?

Tags: snap, beagleboneblack, minikube

I'm trying to install snapcraft on a Beaglebone Blue, which is running:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ uname -a
Linux beaglebone 4.19.94-ti-r42 #1buster SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 31 19:38:29 UTC 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

But when I do, I get this error:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ sudo snap install snapcraft --classic
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "core22" (1034) (snap "core22" assumes unsupported features: snapd2.55.5 (try to update snapd and refresh the core snap))
```

When I try to upgrade snapd I get this:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade snapd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
snapd is already the newest version (2.37.4-1+deb10u3).
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

My plan is to find the oldest version of core22 that works on snapd version 2.37.4, and then find the version of snapcraft that uses that version of core22. I've visited the core22 github repo, and couldn't find past versions. It doesn't look like they have a release structure.

If this is feasible, how could I do that? If it isn't feasible, is there any other way to get microk8s on this machine?

Comment: Can't you release upgrade whatever Debian based OS you're running in the board?

Comment: Can I? I wasn't able to find a more recent release on Beagleboard's website, at least not for the Blue model.